# Alphabetical sort ordering in C language

Tags: c, alphabetical-sort

I need to Alphabetical sort ordering is defined by the ordinal values of the   characters

```
Jenny Craig,47                   
Billy Bob,33
Jenny Craig,29
Simon Says,234
```

The output would be

```
Billy Bob (33)
Jenny Craig (29)
Jenny Craig (47)
Simon Says (234)
```

Here is my code is a little bit large

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80     
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 500    
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50       

typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    Student* next;              // Pointer to next student in a list };

bool comesBefore(const Student* student1, const Student* student2) {
    int name_compare = strcmp(student1->name, student2->name);
    if (name_compare < 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (name_compare == 0) {
        int age1 = student1->age;
        int age2 = student2->age;
        if (age1 > age2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; }

Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL)
        return student;

    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }

    for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
         curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != true;
         prev = curr, curr = curr->next);

    assert(prev != NULL);   
    student->next = curr;  
    prev->next = student;
    return list; 
}


// Create a pool of student records to be allocated on demand

Student studentPool[MAX_NUM_STUDENTS];  // The student pool int
firstFree = 0; // Return a pointer to a new student record from the pool, 

Student* newStudent(const char* name, int age) {
    Student* student = NULL;
    if (firstFree < MAX_NUM_STUDENTS) {
        student = &studentPool[firstFree];
        firstFree += 1;
        strncpy(student->name, name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        student->name[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Make sure it's    
        student->age = age;
        student->next = NULL;
    }
    return student; 
}


 Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file) {
    char *buffer;  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    buffer = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    Student* student = NULL;   

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {           // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the name
            student = newStudent(buffer, age);
        }
    }
    return student; 
}


Student* readStudents(FILE *file) {
    Student* first = NULL;     // Pointer to the first student in the list
    Student* last = NULL;      // Pointer to the last student in the list
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;   // Empty list case
        }
        else {          
            (insert(student,first))->next= first;   
            first = insert(student,first);
        }
        student= readOneStudent(file);
    }
    return first; 
}


// printOneStudent: prints a single student, passed by value

void printOneStudent(Student student) {
    printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age); }


// printStudents: print all students in a list of students, passed
// by reference 

void printStudents(const Student* student) {
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    } }

// Main program. Read a linked list of students from a csv file,
then display // the contents of that list.

int main(void) {
    FILE* inputFile = stdin;
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
    }
    else {
        Student* studentList = readStudents(inputFile);
        printStudents(studentList);
    } 
}
```

so what I got is

```
nothing
```

My another test is right the input is and this one works fine

```
 input                             output

Zaphod Beeblebrox,250              Albert Einstein (7)
Albert Einstein,133                Albert Einstein (133)
Albert Einstein,7                   Zaphod Beeblebrox (250)
```

another test is -------------------------   and should output

```
A,1                            A (1)
A,2                            A (2)
A,33                           A (33)
```

and I got nothing
any suggestion would be be appreciated :)

Comment: `qsort(...,strcmp)`?

Comment: where should I add to?

Comment: @EOF: OP wants to *insert* each new student right into the correct position when adding one. A good idea, and I don't think `qsort` can be used with that. The partial output suggests that somewhere the linking-in fails.

Comment: `(insert(first, student))->next= first; first = insert(first, student);` --> `first = insert(student, first);`

Comment: and `(age1 > age2)` --> `(age1 < age2)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY   Sir I have a question . Why you just write corrections in comment and why not post as answers ? Most of your comments are really more helpful than the actual answer's posted .

Comment: @ameyCU For one thing, this site isn't a debugging service.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Well justified Sir !! . Thanks  for you response :)

Comment: Note do not compare with `true`/`false` (e.g. `comesBefore(student, curr) != true`). Use `!comesBefore(student, curr)`. This is much better understandable - just speak out loud.

Comment: yeah, if the name same the age should be form small to big

Comment: You are using linked list.. not array?